# Easy Alignment/Indention in HTML for Mathematical operation

Tags: html, css, math, tags

I'm having a hard time doing this. Kindly help me do this in simple way.[image]

I need to make this all aligned. Because it's a math addition operation.

My current code is this: [image: html code but the result is not aligned]

But this result not aligned. Are they right? Kindly help me to make them aligned.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Updated. Thanks for letting me know. :)

Comment: You could try using table or css grid

Comment: Please show your "current code" as text rather than as a graphic. That would allow us to copy-and-paste your code into our own text editors. That would also make it easier for web search to find this question later. Also, I see no attempt at alignment in that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code below. I simply used tables to align the data 
(reference: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

```css
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
   
td{
    width: 100px;
}
   
.sum{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
     <table>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>MYR 7,000</td>
            <td>x 6%</td>
            <td>=</td>
            <td>MYR 420</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>MYR 13,500</td>
            <td>x 8%</td>
            <td>=</td>
            <td>MYR 1,040</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>MYR 15,000</td>
            <td>x 10%</td>
            <td>=</td>
            <td>MYR 1,500</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="sum">Net Loss</td>
            <td class="sum">MYR 35,000</td>
            <td class="sum"></td>
            <td class="sum">Rebate</td>
            <td class="sum">MYR 1,690</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, use `&nbsp;` whereever you want space.
example 
 `18 &nbsp; * &nbsp; 2 &nbsp;= &nbsp; 36`